# Can you post data to DynamoDB from a static website hosted on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to build a static website to host on S3. A user should be able to input their location, age and the plan benefits there looking for and based on this the website should return a insurance plan recommendation and a quote price. Is this possible to do? I do not know if S3 allows you to post data and record in DynamoDB. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The website you're describing is not static - users need to be able to interact, get dynamic content, and have it saved somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You'd have a single-page app hosted statically on S3, that then authenticates with and writes to Dynamo. Amazon even provide a library (Amplify) to hell you do that.

Comment: @IMSoP it's not a static site, but it can still be hosted statically if it's an SPA

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right, I was just pointing out that the question contradicts itself by starting with "I am trying to build a static website".